# Django-Rest get URL of related children list

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I got a simple model related to django contrib auth User model. I'd like to have a CRUD for Company, but with related elements set as an url of a list rather then a list of elements (i.e. a link to employees list rather than list of urls of single employee). What's missing here?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=256)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

from .models import Company

class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializers):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'employees')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializers):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email') # and so on
```

view.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from .models import Company

from .serializers import UserSerializer, CompanySerializer

class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

class CompanyViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from django conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import CompanyViewSet, UserViewSet
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'company', CompanyViewSet)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [url(r^api/, include(router.urls))]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Hyperlinked Identity Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield). For you, it might look something like this:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializers):
    employee_listing = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='employee-list')

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'employee_listing')
```

Comment: [Hyperlinked Identity Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield) is what I think about, but there's no url called `employee-list` (if I don't declare it explicite). I tried with `users-list` but it didn't work neither.

Comment: @alekwisnia It makes sense that there's no employee-list, I was just going based off of your serializer fields. Try `user-list` first, just to be diligent, since Django tends to create singular names off of models (like 'user-list' and 'user-detail'.